# UICollectionView Location for Supplementary Header

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am looking to put a header on my collection view's sections. I have a collectionview embedded inside a tablebview. Using the section headers of the tableview puts the header too far from the content. Putting the section header as part of the collection view; however, is putting that header on top of the collection view cell itself. I am looking for some space between the section header and the section detail.

```
func setup() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = THUMB_SIZE
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 25
        layout.sectionInset.right = layout.itemSize.width / 2
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "collectionView")
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true
        collectionView.register(MainCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cvCell")
        self.addSubview(collectionView)

        self.collectionView.register(HeaderCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "headerCell")
    }

    // MARK: - Collectionview Delegate & Datasource

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return topics.shows.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cvCell", for: indexPath) as! MainCVCell

        cell.show = topics.shows[indexPath.row]
        cell.selectedIndex = indexPath.row

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate.selectedMedia(showID: topics.shows[indexPath.row])
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath)
        if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderCVCell
            headerView.headerText = topics.title
            return headerView
        } else {
            return footerView
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 172, height: 60)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return .zero
    }
```

Now for collection view header cell:

```
class HeaderCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var headerText:String! {
        didSet {
            setup()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    private func setup() {
        let headerLabel = UILabel()
        headerLabel.text = headerText
        headerLabel.textColor = .white
        headerLabel.sizeToFit()

        self.subviews.forEach {$0.removeFromSuperview()}
        self.addSubview(headerLabel)
    }
}
```

One thing I noted by putting a background color on the header cell itself, is that the height of the header cell is equaling the height of the collection view. There does not though seem to be anyway that I can adjust the height of the header view cell independently of the collection view cells. If I change `layout.itemSize` it changes the size for both the header and the content. If I use `layout.headerReferenceSize`, it does not change anything. I am also using the delegate method as you can see from the code. Per the documentation it appears that it won't look at the height when in a horizontal scrolling situation such as this is. I have also tried to set the frame of the header cell directly but this is ignored.

Net, my section header is crashing into my regular content in the collection view. I suspect this might be because the height of the header is the height of the collection view and thus it is being positioned as high as it can go. I cannot change the height nor find any other way to separate the header from the content.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar set up and in my Header file, I have the size set with:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: frame.width / 2 + 60, height: frame.height)
}
```

And, if you want to create some spacing, you can use insets. Setting the top to a negative number should show some space after the header.

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

Comment: Your first delegate method is basically the same as my `layout.itemsize`. The second method I had tried by using `layout.sectionInset.top`. This doesn't work either as the title just gets cut-off as the negative number gets larger. I think this comes back to the header cell height being the height of the collection view. There is no room for it to go. As mentioned, I cannot seem to reduce the height of the header cell.